# Python regular expression to extract last name, first name, middle initial from text block

Tags: python, regex

Please help me with correct regex to get below output

```py
import re
text="name of company.\nlastname, firstname - 12345\nDates of Service Diag Xref Proc Code Voucher POS/TOS Units Provider Al/As Other Plan Bill Amt Receipts Net"
Re_text = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+),\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+([A-Za-z]+)( - +\d+$)')
```

Expected output:

```
lastname
firstname
Middle initial (might not come for all scenarios)
12345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)([A-Za-z]+)(?:,\s+([A-Za-z]+))?,\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+-\s+(\d+)$
([^\W\d_]+)(?:,\s+([^\W\d_]+))?,\s+([^\W\d_]+)\s+-\s+(\d+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2kg9ny/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - a `re.M` flag inline variant
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Group 1: any one or more ASCII letters (`[^\W\d_]+` matches any one or more Unicode letters)
- `(?:,\s+([A-Za-z]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of a comma, one or more whitespaces, and then one or more letters captured into Group 2
- `,\s+` - a comma and one or more whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Group 3: any one or more ASCII letters (`[^\W\d_]+` matches any one or more Unicode letters)
- `\s+-\s+` - a hyphen enclosed with one or more whitespacs
- `(\d+)` - Group 4: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qpDk0j):

```py
import re
text="name of company.\nlastname, firstname - 12345\nDates of Service Diag Xref Proc Code Voucher POS/TOS Units Provider Al/As Other Plan Bill Amt Receipts Net"
Re_text = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+)(?:,\s+([A-Za-z]+))?,\s+([A-Za-z]+)\s+-\s+(\d+)$', re.M)
m = Re_text.search(text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
    print(m.group(3))
    print(m.group(4))
```

Output:

```
lastname
None
firstname
12345
```

Comment: Looks like a fine answer to me.